# GFCI and light fixture not working

Tags: light-fixture, gfci

I have a GFCI on the outside of home that I cannot push the test button to test and I replaced it. A new one is doing the same thing as well not allowed me to test I believe it is hooked up to a switch on the inside of the home and in that same panel there is a dimmer switch that controls a light fixture in the kitchen that is also not working. There are other receptacles in the room that work these two are the only things not working with the GFCI on the outside, and the kitchen light on the inside.

Comment: Have you flipped all your breakers on and off? Sometimes when a breaker trips, it's not obviously tripped.

Comment: Yes there are other receptacles and lights that are on the same breaker that also work

Comment: Could it be the wire is burnt out I had my Traeger smoker plugged into that receptacle until it stopped working never mind the reason for the GFCI

Comment: Turn off the breaker. Remove the GFCI/receptacle. Carefully note which wires are line hot and line neutral and separate them. Turn on the breaker. **Carefully** test to see what voltage between line hot and line neutral and between each of those and ground. Turn off the breaker. Report what you found. If 120V hot-neutral and hot-ground and 0V neutral-ground then reconnect the GFCI/receptacle but do **NOT** connect any addition ("load") wires. Test.

Comment: I have not check the voltage yet but there’s no load wire. I only have a hot a neutral and ground connected to the GFCI.

Comment: The switch on the inside controls the outside light not the receptacle outside. Could the problem be in the light fixture itself

Comment: Could the GFCI power be connected to the light fixture?

Comment: The original post said, "I believe it is hooked up to a switch," but the comment said, "The switch on the inside controls the outside light not the receptacle."  This is confusing and lacks detail about the problem.  There is also no question asked in the original post.  Please work on improving the question by clicking the edit link above.  Also please describe whether or not you have used the GFCI Reset button.

Comment: Yes, I can see how this is confusing when you’re not actually looking at the problem there is a GFCI outside. There’s also a light outside I thought that’s why I said I believe that they were connected, but I was totally wrong. The switch only controls the light outside, not the receptacle with the GFCI, the GFCI receptacle is not working light outside is not working and also the dining room light is not working the outside light and the dining room light are on the same interior switch box. Sorry for the confusion.